# DisplayFormat DataAnnotation not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 5 and I'm trying to format a phone number. I found some examples but I can't seem to get any of them to work. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
[DisplayName("Phone Number")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

as well as I tried this...although I don't need this as a required field. I'm not sure if the ReqularExpression will make it required?

```
[DisplayName("Phone Number")]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

***UPDATE***

Sorry I wasn't clear in my original post but all I'm looking to do is to display a phone number in a ###-###-#### format when I display it in my Edit View using the EditFor helper. It's not a required field and I guess the only validation I really need is the fact that it would be numbers. I'm going to strip out all the dashes when I actually store it in the database.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is what I currently have in my ViewModel as well as the View. This just shows the phone number without any formatting in my edit. As a side note in case it makes a difference I'm using MVC 5.2.3.

```
[DisplayName("Phone Number")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a specific format that you want? in the last example you gave, you have 2 types of validation which is unnecessary.. also *but I can't seem to get any of them to work*.. do you mean that an error message isn't appearing or the validation isn't working?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. I update my original post. At the moment I'm not really looking for validation, I'm just looking to format the data in the Edit View so it will look presentable. I'm not getting errors, it's just not formatting the data.

Comment: Okay, so it is not displaying correctly in your Edit View, how are you calling that property in that view? For example `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)`?

Comment: Take a look at my original post. I have the code from the View there. I'm using an @Html.EditFor.

Comment: Okay, then the reason as to why it's not displaying correctly in your Edit view is bc that is the way the phone number was saved.. so the *regular expression* I gave in my answer will validate against phone numbers being entered in incorrectly.. if you use the solution i gave in my UPDATE, then go to details.. how is it displayed since in the Details view it is DisplayFor and not EditorFor

Comment: You cannot format a `string` - the only way your `DataFormatString` would work is if property `PhoneNumber` was numeric (but the of course validation would fail because of your regex). Applying a `RegularExpression` will not make it 'required' (unless you also apply a `[Required]` attribute - leaving the textbox empty not add an error message). Why are you stripping the dashes when you save it? - just save it as it is and apply the `[RegularExpression]` attribute and it will all work as expected.

Comment: No real reason that I'm saving the phone number without the dashes. I guess I would then need to apply some jQuery on the Create View to make it automatically set the textbox in the ###-###-#### format so that they would be consistent and not let someone be able to use another format like (###) ### - ####?

Comment: @Caverman, You don't need any jQuery - the `[RegularExpression]` attribute will take care of both client and server side validation.

Comment: I'm trying to display a decimal value without decimals, so I use {0:N0} format, and it didn't work either...
        [Display(Name = "Días de crédito"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
        public Nullable<decimal> DIASCREDITO; 
 It Works after I added the property ApplyFormatInEditMode = true
 
 'code'        [Display(Name = "Días de crédito"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<decimal> DIASCREDITO;
'code'

Comment: It Works after I added the property ApplyFormatInEditMode = true
`code` 
`        [Display(Name = "Días de crédito"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`
`        public Nullable<decimal> DIASCREDITO;` `code`

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear on exactly what you want here.

This should work for validation purposes.

```
[DisplayName("Phone Number")]
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter the phone number as XXX-XXX-XXXX")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Also, in your view you need to add *ValidationMessageFor*:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

To get the phone number to display correctly in the Edit View:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Comment: Still not sure why but it's not working for me. I know my View is using this ViewModel properly because I changed the DisplayName annotation and that shows up. This is what I have above my PhoneNumber property in the VM. [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Comment: @Caverman so if you create a new record with a new phone number.. does the validation work if you enter a phone number that is not correctly formatted like you want? If you enter a phone number with the correct formatting, save it, then go back to your edit view and does it display the way you entered it?

Comment: I'll have to work on that. I'm just starting to build this app as side project/example for me. I manually added records to the DB and have been working on my Edit View. I've made changes to my ViewModel since I initially started and I need to go back and fix up my Create form.

Comment: I've been working on this on/off over the last week or so. Still I'm not getting it to work. In some of the research I've it looks like the they use a "Long" as the property type where I'm using a "String". Do you think this would really make the difference? I guess theoretically it should be a Long or Int so I might just change everything over anyway.

Comment: BTW, I fixed my Create page to use my ViewModel and got that page working. However, that didn't seem to fix my formatting with the phone number. I'm now looking into using a jQuery plug in as an option as well.

Comment: @Caverman In all of my applications, I give my phone numbers a type of `string`.  There might be a difference in efficiency if you change it to `long`, but whether or not it will be on the positive side or negative side, I do not know.

Comment: So tell me, what is your *Create* page doing that it didn't do before?

Comment: Initially it was set to use the entity class (CustomerCall) which was mapped to my DB table and I changed to it over to using my CustomerCallVM and added some DropDownLists for things like CallTypes and CallStatus. The Create page was initially scaffold out when I created the Controller and I told it to create the views as well.

Comment: I might create a whole new test controller and some views and see if that works. I think all the code is correct but I must be missing something I'm just not catching. Maybe another simple controller/pages will do the trick just so i can see it working.

Comment: @Caverman gotcha, okay so I am trying to remember where we left off.. so on your *Edit* view.. your phone number field is displaying in the wrong format.. which is confusing because on your Edit field you are editing the phone number that is already in the database.. so if you entered in a phone number (for example: 2134-244-532) then that is how it's going to appear in your Edit.. now if you put validation on that property and try to enter the phone number like the example above then it should throw an error

Comment: I'm not getting it to format as a phone number at all. Not in Edit or Create view even though I have it set in the DataAnnotation. However I know the view is picking up some DataAnnotation because if I change the DisplayName in the class then that shows up. It's just not picking up the sting.format to make it look like a phone number. Right now it's just displaying all numeric (ex: 9725551212). I'm not ever worried about validation at the moment.

Comment: @Caverman you are still using the displayformat in your question or have you changed it?

Comment: still using what you posted.