# Confused with difference in MVC 5 TextBoxFor, EditFor, and TextAreaFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been having problems getting formatting to work in my MVC 5 View. The View was scaffold as a TextAreaFor. I added DataFormatting for my property in my ViewModel but it doesn't actually format for me. From everything I have researched I'm formatting the ViewModel correctly but I haven't been able to figure out why the formatting isn't actually working.

So, I tried using @Html.EditFor. That seemed to make the date formatting work but it didn't to apply the Bootstrap "form-control" class. I then tried @Html.TextBoxFor and it responded like the @Html.TextAreaFor, no formatting but did apply the Bootstrap class.

I don't know which one to use and what else I need to do to get my View to not only format the date but to also apply the Bootstrap CSS.

Here is my ViewModel property.

```
[DisplayName("Call Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? CallDate { get; set; }
```

This is the original TextAreaFor that the scaffolding created. No formatting but Bootstap CSS works.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CallDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CallDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CallDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the EditFor that formats the date but doesn't apply Bootstrap CSS.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CallDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CallDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CallDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the TextBoxFor that responded like the TextAreaFor.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CallDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CallDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add html attributes using `@Html.EditorFor()` you must be using MVC-5.1+, and if you are, then the usage is

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CallDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-control datepicker" }})
```

If you not using MVC-5.1+, and you want to generate a textbox and also format the date value, then the usage is (where the 2nd parameter is the format string)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CallDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

Note that `@Html.TextAreaFor()` generate a `<textarea>` element for multi-line text and would not be appropriate for a `DateTime` property.

Comment: Thanks! The change for MVC 5.1+ must have been my issue all along. I'm on 5.2.3 and didn't realize there was a difference in how CSS was passed into the EditFor.

Comment: You tagged it `asp.net-mvc-4` so could not be sure :)

Comment: They don't have asp.net-mvc-5 so I figured 4 was as close as I could get. I'm still having an issue with formatting but this time it's on a phone number. I've got a post I started on it a while back but I still haven't been able to get it to work. Is there a way I can send you a link or tag you in it so you can look it over and see if you can determine what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I just added the tag for you :) Was it [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301817/displayformat-dataannotation-not-working). If not add link here and I'll take a look tomorrow (its late here)